# c++ Shared library error after code migration to CentOS

Tags: c++, centos, libpcap

I was previously working on ubuntu .My c++ code was executing well over there then I switched to Centos 6.3 and compiled my code the same way I compiled it on
ubuntu using g++. Now, on centos when I run the executable of my code, I get the following error.

Here is how I make the executable on centos

```
g++ tcp.cpp -o tcp -lcrafter
```

error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrafter.so.0 : cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory.
```

Edit:

It runs using the command below but there was no need to provide path in Ubuntu:

```
gcc -o tcp tcp.c -L/usr/local/lib -lfoo -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
```

How can I do this without adding path every time ?

Comment: What does `ldd -r tcp` say? Just in case, you are not using dlopen/sym/close in tcp.cpp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write in LD_LIBRARY_PATH path for directory which contain this library: LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /path/to/your/library

Comment: How do you know it is not in the system path or not dlopen/sym/close?

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to the accepted answer. You may invoke the following Linux command in a directory with `libcrafter`:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

`ldconfig` utility [creates](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories